# Split tags in python

Tags: python, split, template-engine

I have a file that contains this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Hello! - {{ today }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ runner_up }} 
         avasd
         {{ blabla }}
        sdvas
        {{ oooo }}
   </body>
</html>
```

What is the best or most Pythonic way to extract the `{{today}}`, `{{runner_up}}`, etc.?

I know it can be done with splits/regular expressions, but I wondered if there were another way.

PS: consider the data loaded in a variable called `thedata`.

Edit: I think that the HTML example was bad, because it directed some commenters to BeautifulSoup. So, here is a new input data:

```
Fix grammatical or {{spelling}} errors.

Clarify meaning without changing it.

Correct minor {{mistakes}}.

Add related resources or links.

Always respect the original {{author}}.
```

Output:

```
spelling
mistakes
author
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the results once you have it extracted?  I ask only because I think it's relevant to answering the question. Are you done once you extract these values or are you trying to design some kind of template grammar in which case a lexer/parser might be a better solution?

Comment: I am going to eval them (creating a simple template engine)

Comment: Since your syntax is identical to Jinja and Django, you could simply use their template engines.  Or their template engine parsers.

Comment: Or just use str.format() if you can use single braces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mmkay, well here's a generator solution that seems to work well for me.  You can also provide different open and close tags if you like.

```
def get_tags(s, open_delim  ='{{', 
                close_delim ='}}' ):

   while True:

      # Search for the next two delimiters in the source text
      start = s.find(open_delim)
      end   = s.find(close_delim)

      # We found a non-empty match
      if -1 < start < end:

         # Skip the length of the open delimiter
         start += len(open_delim)

         # Spit out the tag
         yield s[start:end].strip()

         # Truncate string to start from last match
         s = s[end+len(close_delim):]

      else:
         return
```

Run against your target input like so:

```
# prints: today, runner_up, blabla, oooo
for tag in get_tags(html):
    print tag
```

Edit: it also works against your new example :).  In my obviously quick testing, it also seemed to handle malformed tags in a reasonable way, though I make no guarantees of its robustness!

Comment: Consider, s = '}} {{ tag }}'. Use `s.find(close_delim, start)`

Answer (score 3):

try [templatemaker](http://code.google.com/p/templatemaker/), a reverse-template maker. it can actually learn them automatically from examples!

Comment: It is equivalent to `re.search('{{(.*?)}}', thedata).groups()` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said no regex/split, but I couldn't help but try for a one-liner solution:

```
import re
for s in re.findall("\{\{.*\}\}",thedata):
        print s.replace("{","").replace("}","")
```

EDIT: JFS

Compare:

```
>>> re.findall('\{\{.*\}\}', '{{a}}b{{c}}')
['{{a}}b{{c}}']
>>> re.findall('{{(.+?)}}', '{{a}}b{{c}}')
['a', 'c']
```

Comment: Am I crazy, or are you checking for runs of non-space characters in the source data?  In the first example, the tags are padded with spaces.  Won't this break?

Comment: Yeah, I'm right.  Doesn't work against the first example.  -1

Comment: Aha, you're right. I changed it to match {{  absolutely anything }}. If you don't want it to match {{}} then replace .* with .+

Comment: It is greedy. It eats too much. Use: `print re.findall(r'{{(.+?)}}', thedata)`

Comment: I thought so too @JF but it didn't seem to break when I tested. @Ryan, I removed the downvote.

Comment: @Triptych: I've added example for 'greedy'.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is that straightforward, a simple regex would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

J.F. Sebastian wrote this in a comment but I thought it was good enough to deserve its own answer:

```
re.findall(r'{{(.+?)}}', thestring)
```

I know the OP was asking for a way that didn't involve splits or regexes - so maybe this doesn't *quite* answer the question as stated. But this one line of code definitely gets my vote as the most Pythonic way to accomplish the task.

Comment: actually I was tempted to vote it (I didn't have that in mind when I said reg expressions) but it would be unfair for the other answer. To bad I can't vote both :(